# konsole bash: file/dir not found or no permission

Tags: bash, input-devices, konsole

1. I inadvertedly opended a konsole and was confused by login (user ID, connect), entered wrong details and shut down the computer rather than exiting as required.
2. `/proc/bus/input/devices`   Response: `bash: proc/bus/input/devices: File or directory not found`
3. I reinstalled Ubuntu, but the response now is: `-bash: … path: no permission`.
   I would have expected a list as a response in item 2.
   On the GUI I can browse to the devices file and open it: 17 paragraphs.

Questions:

a) Is the not found message caused by 1? By a reinstall on an encrypted hard drive?

b) Can I rectify this by another reinstall where I have to do something special?

Comment: It looks to me like you just forgot to type the `cat` command  and/or missed the leading `/`. Try `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

Comment: 1 Added cat as suggested and working
2 My mistake, forgot backslash
3 I am working through a guidebook and the author wrote "the command x lists all connected input devices". So I misinterpreted a navigation or he should have been more precise.